# Update to 2.4.5-p1 deleted Php files in Pub Folder

Tags: patches, magento2.4.5, index.php, pub

I recently updated a local Shop to 2.4.5-p1. The update seems to have deleted all contents from my [Mageroot]/pub folder except for sub-folders. Notably this affected index.php. Is there any way to regenerate the default contents of that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: This did unfortunately not regenerate any of the missing files. My hunch ist that I will have to do a complete reinstall.

Comment: could you let me know some missing files and folders?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting the missing files from my integration-server.
My guess is that I did something wrong at the composer require step. Thank you to everyone who answered.